# Is it a valid chemical?

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem, graph-theory, chemistry

Non-metals typically* have a fixed number of covalent bonds in every chemical they are part of. Given the number of bonds every element requires, output whether it's possible to construct a *single* molecule from the given chemicals, such that every atom has it's desired number of bonds.

In other words, output if it's possible to construct a connected undirected multigraph without self-loops so that each node has the number of edges equal to the corresponding number listed in the input.

### Test Cases

Falsey:

- `[1]` A single element has nothing to bond with
- `[4]` Atoms can not bond with themselves
- `[1, 1, 1, 1]` Each atom is saturated after single bond, so it's impossible to connect all 4 of them together. It can form 2 pairs but not a single molecule.
- `[0, 0]` Two separate helium "molecules"
- `[1, 3]`
- `[2, 3]`
- `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]`

Truthy:

- `[1, 1]` (Hydrogen Gas: H-H → `1-1`)
- `[4, 2, 2]` (Carbon Dioxide: O=C=O → `2=4=2`)
- `[3, 3]` (Nitrogen Gas: N≡N → `3≡3`)
- `[2, 2, 2]` (Ozone*: \$\newcommand{\tripow}[3]{ _{#1}{\stackrel{#2}{\triangle}}_{#3}} \tripow{O}{O}{O}\$ → \$\tripow{2}{2}{2}\$)
- `[0]` (Helium: He → `0`)
- `[3, 2, 1]` (Nitroxyl: O=N-H → `2=3-1`)
- `[3, 3, 3, 3]` (Tetrazete: \$\begin{array}{ccccccc}N&-&N& &3&-&3\\\
  ||& &||& → &||& &||\\\
  N&-&N& &3&-&3\end{array}\$)
- `[4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`
- `[4, 2, 2, 1, 1]`
- `[3, 3, 2, 1, 1]`

Here are the Falsey/Truthy test cases as two lists of lists:

```
[[1], [4], [1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]]
[[1, 1], [4, 2, 2], [3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [0], [3, 2, 1], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [4, 2, 2, 1, 1], [3, 3, 2, 1, 1]]
```

### Clarifications

- You may assume the input is non-empty and all values are positive or zero.
- You may choose any 2 distinct values for truthy or falsy, or output truthy/falsy using your language's convention (swapping is allowed). See the tag wiki [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem)

*I've been told real chemistry is a lot more complex than this, but you can ignore the complexities in this challenge.

Comment: In other words: Determine whether it is possible to construct a connected graph with the given vertex degrees, allowing multiple edges between a pair of vertices. (Is there a limit to that?)

Comment: For the purpose of this question there is no limit to the number of bonds between 2 atoms

Comment: I've clarified the first few truthy test cases of the actual chemicals. Feel free to change it or revert it if it isn't to your liking.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Impressive latex for the ozone

Comment: @mousetail The bottom two should be a bit lower tbh, but I've just [copy-pasted it from the (bottom) answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307833/how-to-represent-the-triangle-of-power-in-latex). An inline ASCII triangle was a bit more complex to make. ;)

Comment: @Seggan Tetrahedrane does not seem to fit the chemical formula N4

Comment: @mousetail ive edited the text, actual N4 does not link in a tetrahedron

Comment: Was this really ready to re-open? It looks like a clear instance of [rules inferred from test cases](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8078/20260). I wouldn't have understood the challenge without looking in the comments. Also, the test cases are in a [hard-to-use format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8101/20260).

Comment: The first paragraph should explain the rules exactly, anything unclear there?

Comment: Also you can trivially extract the test cases with `[...$$('pre')].map(i=>i.innerText)`

Comment: @mousetail Reading the mention of chemicals and non-metals and covalent bonds made me think that considerations of geometry or valence electrons or electronegativity were going to be relevant. I would have preferred xigoi's purely math explanation.

Comment: Another interesting related https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/bridges.html

Comment: @xnor the chemical explanation is much more intuitive to me who has no graph theory background

Comment: @mousetail i couldnt have thought of that JS, itd be better to make the testcases easier to parse

Comment: @Seggan The test cases are easier to parse at the bottom (see "_Here are the Falsey/Truthy test cases as two lists of lists_")

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[4,4,3,3,1,1]` \$\begin{array}{ccccccc}3&-&4&-&1\\\ ||& &||& & &\\\ 3&-&4&-&1\end{array}\$ (cycle with two additional connections) and `[4,4,3,3,3,3]` \$\begin{array}{ccccccc}3&-&4&-&3\\\ ||& &||& &||&\\\ 3&-&4&-&3\end{array}\$ (two connected cycles).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I don't think either of your suggestions actually requires finding said cycles as `[4,4,3,3,3,3]` can be achieved with \begin{array}{ccccccc}3\equiv 4-3=3-4\equiv3\end{array} while `[4,4,3,3,1,1]` can be achieved with \begin{array}{ccccccc}1-3=4=4=3-1\end{array}

Answer (score 27):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>61 60 59 58</s> 51 bytes

```python
lambda x:len(x)-2<~sum(x)%2*all(x)*sum(x)/2>=max(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LDoMgEDzXr@DSKIamgpxM7bFf0Jv1sE01miAaH4le@usUFFNNGzbszjDDQDP1RS1DlccPJaB6vgCNkcikN@ITu7y7odLTkfkghB78BZ/ZNa5g1JNq2lL2nnsD0WVT5GInr1sEqJQoSWhKUMLNRgmyZVBAUGDZ0HRm@1c113rGjDyNnMOSBQTlHmDs2Oh7O/TFT7SN4rOdmTHc3ThTgeWZVRvJUta7fc7Gx1dEd8YNwQknoV6U7KBef36iPg)

-1 thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen

-7 thanks to @xnor

Uses theorem 2 from [this paper](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-Realizability-of-a-Set-of-Integers-as-Degrees-of-Hakimi/83b1608fb33eef2467a53f6ccffed559df7408dc).

It says a degree sequence is realizable as a connected multigraph with no self-loops if and only if it is `[0]`, or:

0. All degrees are positive.
1. The sum of the degree sequence is even.
2. The biggest degree is less than or equal to the sum of the rest of the degrees. That is, `sum(x)-max(x)>=max(x)`, or equivalently `sum(x)/2>=max(x)`
3. The number of edges, which is half the sum of degrees, is greater or equal to \$n-1\$, where \$n\$ is the number of vertices.

`~sum(x)%2*all(x)*sum(x)/2` is equal to `sum(x)/2` is the first two conditions are satisfied, and `0` otherwise.

If it is equal to `0`, it implies `len(x)-2<0>=max(x)`, so `len(x)==1, max(x)==0` and therefore `x==[0]`.

Otherwise, if the first two conditions are satisfied, it tests the third condition with `sum(x)/2>=max(x)`, and the fourth with `len(x)-2<sum(x)/2` (which is equivalent to `len(x)-1<=sum(x)/2` since these are integers according to the second condition).

Comment: `~-len(x)<=` can be `len(x)-2<` for -1 I think?

Comment: This algorithm is way underrated, it is even shorter than the popular algorithms for the graph realization problem.

Comment: I think this works? `lambda l:len(l)-2<~sum(l)%2*all(l)*sum(l)/2>=max(l)` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LDoIwEDzLV/RioKRG@jgR8egXeEMOa4RIUgrhkcjFX68tlAjRdNPdmc502mbsn7XiukhuWkJ1fwCSscxVIPGBnd7dUJlpz0KQ0gzhjI/snFTwMpNu2lL1gX8B2eVj7GOvqFsEqFQoTWlGUCrsRglyZVFEUORYbjtz/auaajljVp7F3m7OAoKKADD2XPS1HfrnT7SLEpOd2ZFvbpyoyPHMqa1kLuddP2flEwuiG@OKEEQQbhYlG2jWn5/oDw "Python 3 – Try It Online")). The idea is that if the sum is odd or there's a 0, the middle term is 0, which forces a length of 1 and a max of 0, so the list must be `[0]`. This has even sum, so odd sum is always banned.

Comment: @mathscat Usually the graph realization problem allows only one edge between each pair of vertices, which complicates things.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 134 bytes

Thanks to all for the motivation to immerse in graph theory! It is wonderful that there is a numerical criterion for connected multigraph. But I was wondering how it worked.
So I didn’t make a port of the same theorem, but I found *an algorithm* that allows you to build a multigraph, if it's possible, or give a message that you can’t. Having studied [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.03747).
Here is the full-code version of Theorem 7 from the paper. It takes list of degrees and print out:

- Render of graph and `True`, if it's possible to make connected multigraph
- Graph and `False`, if only non-connected result is possible
- `None`, if list of degrees is non-graphic

```
multiGraphFromDegrees[degrees_List] :=
  Module[{n = Length@degrees, graph = Graph[{}]},
   data = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {degrees, Range@n}];
   While[n > 1,
    data = ReverseSortBy[data, First];
    data[[1, 1]] -= 1; data[[n, 1]] -= 1;
    graph = 
     EdgeAdd[graph, UndirectedEdge[data[[1, 2]], data[[n, 2]]]];
    data = Select[data, #[[1]] > 0 &];
    n = Length@data;
    ];
   If[n > 0, Print["None"],
    Row[{graph, " Connected: ", ConnectedGraphQ@graph}]
    ]];
```

Example `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3]`:

[image]

Example `[3, 3, 3, 3]`:

[image]

Example `[6, 6, 4]`:

[image]

Example `[5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`:

[image]

Note, that algorithm makes *some example* of graph, if it's possible. So for `[3,3,3,3]` we have not Tetrazet, but other valid chemical. Also result *may be non-planar*, but it's OK for chemicals too.

And here is short version, directly answers the question of challenge (`True` or `False`):

```
(d=#;n=Length@#;Catch[While[n>1,d=ReverseSort[d];d[[1]]-=1;d[[n]]-=1;d=Select[d,#>0&];m=Length@d;If[n-m==2,Throw[False],n=m]]];d=={})&
```

If anyone is interested, I’ll describe the algorithm a little more.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYw9C8IwFAB3f4VQKAopmOoWXikIguAgVnAIbwjNsyk0KaRBh9LfXit@oHDDwcFZFQxZFepSjRWMCw2RcHAgVwWTR2KrQmnkxdQNSZdxpuFEN/IdFa0PUqPQUnLEBPjT3NugoIbKqbMoW8Uo7Geoxf4qXWIBUnY2vr3LnWo6QubAIk43gH5YxuPR1y7klew5m/@yHnD2bZv/lr4YcHwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>58</s> <s>51</s> 45 bytes

*Edit: -6 bytes thanks to pajonk*

```r
\(x,`+`=sum)max(+x^0-1,x)<=all(x)*+x/2*!+x%%2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3dWM0KnQStBNsi0tzNXMTKzS0K-IMdA11KjRtbBNzcjQqNLW0K_SNtBS1K1RVjaCafqRpGGpypWmYgIhkDUMdMNSE8Ax0DDRh4sZQlhGcBVWrg5Az0DHSMYKrMwLrTk4s0VDSRYCYPCW4dqhSEyRtxkgWIUQN4LJGcF1AlToI1SZwxyDrA5uM5CGQDigf4v8FCyA0AA)

Based on [xnor's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259143/is-it-a-valid-chemical#comment571503_259154) on [Command master's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154/95126): upvote that!

Comment: Some rearrangements for [-5 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY39WI0KnQStBNsi0tzNXMTKzS0K-IMdI10KnQNNW0Sc3I0KjS1tCv0jbQUtStUVY2gun6kaRhqcqVpmICIZA1DHTDUhPAMdAw0YeLGUJYRnAVVq4OQM9Ax0jGCqzMC605OLNFQ0kWAmDwluHaoUhMkbcZIFiFEDeCyRnBdQJU6CNUmcMcg6wObjOQhkA4oH-L_BQsgNAA).

Comment: Another [-1](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3dWM0KnQStBNsi0tzNXMTKzS0K-IMdA11KjRtbBNzcjQqNLW0K_SNtBS1K1RVjaCafqRpGGpypWmYgIhkDUMdMNSE8Ax0DDRh4sZQlhGcBVWrg5Az0DHSMYKrMwLrTk4s0VDSRYCYPCW4dqhSEyRtxkgWIUQN4LJGcF1AlToI1SZwxyDrA5uM5CGQDigf4v8FCyA0AA)

Comment: @pajonk - Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Uses [S. L. Hakimi's result](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-Realizability-of-a-Set-of-Integers-as-Degrees-of-Hakimi/83b1608fb33eef2467a53f6ccffed559df7408dc) as aired by [Command Master](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master) in their excellent [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154/53748).

```
ẠȧSH_L’»ṀƲeŻ$
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of non-negative integers and yields `1` if a molecule may be formed or `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrgUnlgd7xPs8aph5aPfDnQ3HNqUe3a3y////aGMdBQSKBQA)**

#### How?

```
ẠȧSH_L’»ṀƲeŻ$ - Link: non-empty list of non-negative integers, D
Ạ             - all (D)? -> 0 if any of D are zero
  S           - sum (D)
 ȧ            - (all?) logical AND (sum)
   H          - halve (that) - call this X
         Ʋ    - last four links as a monad - f(D):
     L        -   length (D)
      ’       -   decrement
        Ṁ     -   maximum (D)
       »      -   (length-1) maximum (maximum(D)) - call this Y
    _         - (X) subtract (Y)
            $ - last two links as a monad - f(Q=that)
           Ż  -   zero range (Q) -> list of integers = [0..floor(Q)] (empty if Q < 0)
          e   -   (Q) exists in (that)?
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

Based on the theorem [found by @CommandMaster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154/58563).

Returns `1` for falsy or `0` for truthy.

```javascript
a=>a.some(v=>!(s+=v,k++,m>v?v:m=v)&a>'0',m=k=s=0)|2*k>s+3|s<m*2|s%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jU/BToUwELzzFfWgtI9KSuGktp70C7xVDhsEn0KpYZ9NTPh3BC2Bd3vJpLs7nelOP8EDVsPH1@m2d2/11KgJlIYUna2pV/qKYqI8b5OEW@0f/Z1Vnt2AjkXMrWoVKsFGeWg1JvmID/YgR7yWU@V6dF2ddu6dxuYZOvwpY3YfGWKykhNTLEfGScAyCU5EYPOlylA31R/yoJ2vZUnKKG3c8ATVkQJRmuz3NhQYm3dGZ2Fee/MyfJ@OW56wvwhvzm2@RVgpEXgZ1IvkH8G7z7jzFeuUnRlX4pIPTL8)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
OÉ›¦IO;IàIg<‚@«P
```

Port of [*@CommandMaster*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154/52210), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f/3Dno4Zdh5Z5@lt7Hl7gmW7zqGGWw6HVAf//R5vomOgYQ2AsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXLf//DnY8adh1aVulvXXl4QWW6zaOGWQ6HVgf81/kfHW0YqxNtAsSGOmAIZBnoGID5xkDSCExC5XQgYgY6RrE6CtEQxSY6RiButDFUOYRnABYxAqsAyuhAZE3gxsDUgXVDrQWpgrFNdEzAulB5IFNiAQ).

**Explanation:**

```
O           # Get the sum of the (implicit) input-list
 É          # Pop and check whether it's odd (0 if even; 1 if odd)
  ›         # Check for each value in the (implicit) input-list whether it's larger
            # (so the sum is even and none are 0)
   ¦        # Remove the very first check (for edge-case input=[0])
IO          # Push the sum of the input-list again
  ;         # Halve it
        ‚   # Pair
   Ià       # the maximum of the input-list
     Ig<    # with the length-1 of the input-list
         @  # Check [sum/2>=max, sum/2>=length-1]
«           # Merge this pair to the earlier list of checks
 P          # Check if all are truthy by taking the product
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 21 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 17.29 bytes

```
XDS2%!>xS2/xMxL1-ZPpP
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FlsjXIKNVBXtKoKN9Ct8K3wMdaMCCgIgclAlC1ZGG-soGOkoGMZCBAA) or
[verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abRSilLsEs_qVJelpSVpuhZbI1yCjVQV7SqCjfQrfCt8DHWjAgoCIHKLXaO8IawFN49GRxvG6ihEm4AIQx0FKALxDHQUDKCixiDaCEojVIGRcWwsV3Q0TJOJjgJQnRGIaYzQBxMygIobQVWDlEAQVC-ywUj6TGA8QxSNMIFYiG8A)

Based on [Command Master's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154/114446). Somehow passes all the test cases.

Outputs \$0\$ for falsy and \$1\$ for truthy.

##### Explanation

```python
XDS2%!>xS2/xMxL1-ZPpP  # Implicit input
XD                     # Store input in x for later
  S2%!                 # Sum is even?
      >                # Is the input greater than this?
       xS2/            # Divide the sum by 2
           xM          # Push the maximum of x
             xL1-      # Get the length and decrement
                 ZP    # Pair together
                   pP  # Sum / 2 greater than or equal to both?
                       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 52 bytes

```
$[a][s:∑a(0=s%2)∧(>=s/2max a)∧(-size a 2)<s/2]
```

Thanks to S. L. Hakimi for solving the problem back in 1962 and @CommandMaster for finding the solution and explaining the relevant bits so clearly.

[image: running the above code on the test cases]

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 13 bytes

```
∑2¦$ṁ±*$:#←c≥
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FtsfdUw0OrRM5eHOxkMbtVSslB-1TUh-1Ll0SXFScjFUzYKbm6INY7miTYDYUEcBioAcAx0FA4iYMZAyglAIFWAEEwLp11EAqjECsozhOqACBhBBI4hCkDQEQXQhm4fQYwLjGCLrgvEhTgcA)

A port of [@Command Master's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154/9288).

The flag `-e` set the interpreter to `CheckExistence` mode, which prints `True` if the computation has any result, and `False` otherwise.

```
∑2¦$ṁ±*$:#←c≥

∑2¦              Divide the sum of the input by 2. Fail if the remainder is not zero.
   $ṁ±*          Multiply it by the sign of the minimum element of the input.
            ≥    Check if the result is greater than or equal to all items of the following list:
       $:#←c       Prepend the length minus 1 to the input
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 18 bytes

```
ʷ{P↕1:Ð-:C0=+?}0U=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FttOba8OeNQ21dDq8ARdK2cDW237WoNQ2yXFScnFUCULbqZFG8ZyRZsAsaGOAhQBOQY6CgYQMWMgZQShoHImOgpAASMgyxguDRUwgAgaQRSCpCEoFmIdAA)

This is extremely slow and takes up a lot of memory.

The idea is to repeatedly delete one edge at a time, until the result equals to `[0]`.

```
ʷ{P↕1:Ð-:C0=+?}0U=

ʷ{            }       Repeat the following function until it fails:
  P                     Fails unless the result is all positive.
   ↕                    Non-deterministically permute the list.
    1:Ð-                Decrement the first two elements of the list.
        :C0=+?          Drop the first element of the list if it is zero.
               0U=    Check if the result is equal to [0].
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 17 bytes

Based on [Command Master's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92727/command-master)

```
∑₂?sṫ$∑≤?∑½?L‹≥WA
```

```
∑₂?sṫ$∑≤?∑½?L‹≥WA
∑₂                  Is the sum of the list even?
  ?sṫ$∑≤            Sort list, swap and sum tail-removed part, is lesser than or equal?
        ?∑½?L‹≥     Is length of list - 1 greater than or equal to half of the sum
               WA   Wrap stack, all truthy?
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiJHigoI/c+G5qyTiiJHiiaQ/4oiRwr0/TOKAueKJpVdBIiwiIiwiWzMsIDMsIDIsIDEsIDFdIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 28 bytes

```
max(dim(Ans)-1,max(Ans))≤min(Ans>0).5sum(Ans)not(fPart(.5sum(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Uses the same method as in [Command Master's Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154).

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 67 bytes

```
Length@x-2<BitNot[Tr@x]~Mod~2*If[AllTrue[x,#>0&],1,0]*Tr@x/2>=Max@x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBda8MgFH3Pr7hksIfWMWPz1DYl26AwWMce@iYyZDOLkDaQOHCE9q9nagw1@5CLXs85V@@5B65KceBKvvG@oPqVLbP@SRw/VJnrG7K@l@q5VnTf5Jqdd/X7mcweC3pXVfvmU1CNrjb4mqEEYTazmluyyXZc57p/aeRR0XjLq1Z8LWO2igqXPvBWtJBB1yUnBF1qtwSBD3vDCLBHF/Yk/ryoXIwcsfLTKtrWDZXmYUNJWGcwmKDBr8ww8zmCobWAoFQyQ8YQIyh@EWZFkbdjXKtysKNcGtjx7aeuJWLTxaRLB2GPE6@2kiF8bWgxqEvHWzIpDACjSMfH/sLcH//PKbAznVNATOf0kzCr/wY)

A port of [@Command Master's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259154/9288).

Explicit Mathematica Code is

```
f[x_List] := Module[{len, bitNotSumMod, allPositive, halfSum, maxVal},
    len = Length[x] - 2;
    bitNotSumMod = BitNot[Total[x]] ~Mod~ 2;
    allPositive = If[AllTrue[x, # > 0 &], 1, 0];
    halfSum = Total[x] / 2;
    maxVal = Max[x];

    len < bitNotSumMod * allPositive * halfSum >= maxVal
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
¬∨﹪Σθ²‹∧⌊θΣθ⊗⌈⊞Ｏθ⊖Ｌθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwDIZfxWOEeRFvngYeNzfwOHaoXbCFNnFpK759jbrwB374vhDrjFg2odZRPGW4coZBoOelBIZbibDum91Rt8OUoKUFek8@buAvaLlwuQdUaN4/OJbkhieKySywKkcrGJGyOh3SI7vv3TbnWqfppG8081wPr/AB) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a valid chemical, nothing if not. Explanation: Based on @CommandMaster's Python answer.

```
    θ                    Input list
   Σ                     Sum
  ﹪                      Modulo
     ²                   Literal integer `2`
 ∨                      Logical Or
         θ              Input list
        ⌊               Minimum
       ∧                Logical And
           θ            Input list
          Σ             Sum
      ‹                 Is less than
                   θ    Input list
                  Ｌ     Length
                 ⊖      Decremented
              ⊞Ｏ        Appended to
                θ       Input list
             ⌈          Maximum
            ⊗           Doubled
¬                       Logical Not
                        Implicitly print
```

- `len(x) - 2 < ~sum(x) % 2 * all(x) * sum(x) / 2 >= max(x)` becomes
- `~sum(x) % 2 * all(x) * sum(x) / 2 >= max(*x, len(x) - 1)` becomes
- `~sum(x) % 2 * all(x) * sum(x) >= 2 * max(*x, len(x) - 1)` becomes
- `not(~sum(x) % 2 * all(x) * sum(x) < 2 * max(*x, len(x) - 1))` becomes
- `not(sum(x) % 2 or all(x) * sum(x) < 2 * max(*x, len(x) - 1))` becomes
- `not(sum(x) % 2 or (min(x) and sum(x)) < 2 * max(*x, len(x) - 1))`.